# Users with untrimmed display names

Tags: discussion, display-names

[Some users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/368578)<sup>1</sup> appear to have untrimmed display names.

Untrimmed display names might become an issue in comment formatting, and in chat we have already experienced some markdown issues with it.

Could this lead to further issues users might not be aware of?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Collation because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266830/he-who-must-not-be-named-aka-anyone-can-ping-everyone-in-chat/266831#266831).

Comment: What are the issues you are having in comment formatting / chat mark down because of this?

Comment: @PeeHaa Mainly some reporting that went bonk, like " post of [username ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/0) "

Comment: I'd like to note that, while I don't think user names should be allowed to start or end with white-space characters, this has been fixed in the script where we noticed the issue. I just assumed that the user names wouldn't have any weird spaces, so I didn't account for there being any.

Comment: I didn't know you can perform SQL searches on StackExchange :O

Comment: @aCodingN00b The SE platform is backed by a MSSQL database system. Developers (such as [balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha)) are able to do whatever SQL searches they want on the system.

Comment: I wonder what the overlap is between space-padded-name lovers and [aficionados of punctuation](http://imgur.com/x4CCvBD)?